# Renaming ID of a layout element does not rename the viewBinding reference

Tags: android, rename, android-viewbinding

Lets say that I have the a layout named **activity_main.xml** and it has an element:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

An activity named **MainActivity.java**. In its' onCreate method, I inflate the above layout using viewBinding, and set text of text view:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    binding.textView.setText("some text");
}
```

Now, if I rename the id of TextView in **activity_main.xml**, by pressing `Shift+F6`
 to something like `@+id/text_view_new`, then the reference in `onCreate` doesn't changed from `binding.textView.setText("some text");` to `binding.textViewNew.setText("some text");`

**Is this behaviour a limitation, a bug or am I doing something wrong**?

Answer (score 1):

> **Is this behaviour a limitation, a bug or am I doing something wrong?**

My thoughts about:

- You doing all as expected
- I think it's not a bug or a limitation, it's just how it's works. Of course, someone could expect magic and change your "textView" to "textViewNew" in activity and someone could say it's a limitation. It's important to understand how View Binding works and whether it could do such a magic or not.

View Binding mechanism generates additional Java Binding-classes. So the magic happened there during build process - class ActivityMainBinding was generated, there was put public field "textView". After getting instance of this class you can write just "binding.textView".

But after renaming "id" in xml it wouldn't be very smart to change this autogenerated class automatically (and that action has to be done if you want to replace "textView" with "textViewNew"). That's why this change doesn't affect anything in code

Comment: It can generate "textViewNew" as soon as I change "text_view" to "text_view_new" in XML, then I don't see why it can't be renamed. Anyways, i just wanted to confirm if I was missing something.

Comment: why it wouldn't be very smart to change this auto generated class?

Comment: @JustAnEuropean, because classes' autogeneration is just an auxiliary part of build process.  During every build auto-generated classes are recreated. Any change there 1) doesn't affect your application and 2) will be erased after next build.